# Methods invoked by runtime in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios

Today I read the [apple documentation on dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000050-dealloc). It reads that

> "You never send a dealloc message directly. Instead, an object’s
>   dealloc method is invoked by the runtime."

In my understanding, it means that we never send dealloc message to an object, only runtime sends dealloc to itself. Correct me if I am wrong.

In addition, I am wondering what other methods are only invoked by runtime just like dealloc.

I read the [runtime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), but had a hard time to understand it. Let's say, why dealloc is not listed in the doc?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're after and perhaps where/if you have bothered to look yourself? [objc/runtime](http://opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-532/runtime/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my understanding, it means that we never send dealloc message to an object

Correct.

> only runtime sends dealloc to itself

The runtime sends dealloc methods to objects when their retain count gets to zero. The runtime doesn't send dealloc to itself (the runtime isn't an object, and deallocating the runtime doesn't make sense!).

Comment: "We" can send messages, "runtime" can send messages, anyone else can send messages?

Comment: Any object can send messages.

Comment: In my understanding, any object can receive messages. I think I get a little confused about what a message sender is. Could you give me a simple example to illustrate a sender and a receiver of a message?

Comment: every object can receive messages. and every object is coming from a class that is a subclass of another class. And the root class that is the superclass of all other classes is NSObject (there is also the NSProxy case which I will ignore). NSObject has methods - NSObject can send itself messages i.e [self alloc] - this implies that every object can send messages (at least to itself).